# preserve double quotes in string while using echo in unix loop

Tags: bash, unix

I have these file names that literally have double quotes in the path to deal with special characters issues, I want to loop through and echo the file paths while preserving the quotes, this seems to remove them:

```
for value in temp/sample."sample.id1".genotypes.txt temp/sample."sample.id2".genotypes.txt; do echo $value; done
```

I tried this but no luck:

```
for value in temp/sample."sample.id1".genotypes.txt temp/sample."sample.id2".genotypes.txt; do echo '${value}'; done
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If you are able to figure out how to get `echo` to display the literal quotes, I suspect this will not solve your actual problem, since your comment "files names that literally have double quotes in the path to deal with special character issues" is rather meaningless.  If your pathnames have literal double quotes, then those double quotes would be considered special characters and accessing the files with such a name would require that they be handled.  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the strings to preserve the double quotes:

```
for value in 'temp/sample."sample.id1".genotypes.txt' 'temp/sample."sample.id2".genotypes.txt'; do 
  echo "$value"
done
```

Otherwise, writing `some."thing"` is identical to `some.thing` because the shell interprets the quotes.

Comment: More than "interprets the quotes": the shell **removes** the quotes, so that it's impossible to know that they were even there. Part of [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: ... or escape the double quotes: `for value in temp/sample.\"sample.id1\".genotypes.txt...`.

Comment: Sure. The idea in both cases is the same: you need to prevent the shell from interpreting them as quote characters.

Comment: Not harmful in this case but I don't like the `echo $value`

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape it :

```
for value in temp/sample.\"sample.id1\".genotypes.txt temp/sample.\"sample.id2\".genotypes.txt; do echo $value; done
```

Answer (score 0):

for things like this, I like to use a slightly different approach that looks like a better design to me:

```
# make an array with the data
mapfile -t ary <<"EOF"
temp/sample."sample.id1".genotypes.txt
temp/sample."sample.id2".genotypes.txt
EOF

# use the data from the array
for f in "${ary[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

It will make your life a bit easier if your data grows, and you can then very easily transfer it to another file. Of course, if it's only for a one-time use (e.g., you made an error when naming your files and you only want to rename them), then learn how to have Bash properly parse the quotes as shown in the other answers (escaping them or using single quotes).